# Get duplicates together with index with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that I created using the "duplicated" function, it looks like this:

```
IX  Campaign_Response   Gender  Presence_of_Child   Marital_Status  Age_Group_ID    Cluster Income_Group    Payer_Type  Race    dwell_type  education   Region  is_duplicated
 7         0               0              1                1             1              18        D                 NK  W           S           2           3   True
27          0              0              1                1             2              13        E                 PK  W           S           5             4 True
43          0              0              1                 1            2              8         H                  NK H            S           5           3  True
The rest of these lines are spaced as above Roughly
80  1   0   1   1   4   7   F   NK  H   S   1   3   True
81  1   0   1   1   4   7   F   NK  H   S   1   3   True
82  1   0   1   1   4   7   F   NK  H   S   1   3   True
```

So what I want is to find the index numbers f the duplicated rows (with an instance of the row? So I want to be able to see instances of row duplication and the row contents to see what the characteristics of the duplicated rows.

I was thinking of some group by but that wiped out the index number and I also need to see the Campaign response which is not included in the "find duplicates" function, I expect that a number of otherwise identical records have differing responses and of course different index numbers...

So desired output could look like: Any alternative way of showing is fine

```
80  1   0   1   1   4   7   F   NK  H   S   1   3   True
81  1   0   1   1   4   7   F   NK  H   S   1   3   True *** <<< indicating dupe of prior record (as many occurrences as required
82  1   0   1   1   4   7   F   NK  H   S   1   3   True
391  1   0   1   1   4   7   F   NK  H   S   1   3   True****
508  1   0   1   1   4   7   F   NK  H   S   1   3   True****
83  1   0   1   1   4   7   F   NK  H   S   1   3   True
108  1   0   1   1   4   7   F   NK  H   S   1   3   True *** another dupe
```

Comment: is there a specific column that you want duplicates of?

Comment: No I'm looking for entire duplicate records (All cols) which I have using the "duplicated" function but no way to see which is a duplicate of which other

Comment: perhaps you could provide a sample desired output.  I think I understand what you want but probably best if you provide  example input (which it seems you have) and a desired output.

Comment: so a duplicate is when all columns are the same, if two rows have one column that is the same but the rest aren't then that's not a duplicate?

Comment: correct for the designated columns ie not the index column and I also do not select the Campaign response column the dups are currently "selected using the function the issue is how to group the records that have been detected as dups together in some way for further viewinganalyis

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your DataFrame is named `df`, you can simply get the index values of duplicates as follows:

```
idx_dups = df[df.duplicated()].index
```

Comment: I have already identified the dups. what I can't see is which indexed record duplicates which others.. I simply get if it is a dup or not, no way to see which records duplicate which other record specifically.

Comment: df.ix[idx_dups] will show the duplicates, along with df[df.duplicated()]

Comment: But it simply displays all duplicated records (the fact that the record has a duplicate)  in index order. No way to see which specific record is the duplicate of which other specific record.